# Hadoop Input File Name Issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am facing an issue as below.
My input folder contains a file named : /xyz/pqr/job_ip/output_upto_Thu_Apr_23_14:53:05_2015.log

When I am starting my hadoop job my job is not able to read the input

If i change the name of the file say

```
mv /xyz/pqr/job_ip/output_upto_Thu_Apr_23_14:53:05_2015.log  /xyz/pqr/job_ip/output_upto_Thu_Apr_23_145305_2015.log
```

Then my job runs fine...

The exception I am getting when I am keeping my file name as output_upto_Thu_Apr_23_14:53:05_2015.log is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:   output_upto_Thu_Apr_23_14:53:05_2015.log
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:50)
at  org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:329)
...
..

Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in  absolute URI:output_upto_Thu_Apr_23_14:53:05_2015.log
at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1804)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:752)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:145)
....
..
.
```

Can some one address as to what is the issue with the file name..

Comment: Give full path of the input path file...

Comment: a dummy path is there in the question..The full path can be /home/user/work/data/job_a_data/input/. In my job , I have given the full path as "/home/user/work/data/job_a_data/input/" to my job as input. Its the input files name which is causing the problem. If i change the files name, then  the issue is getting resolved..

Answer (score 1):

As the error explicitly tells you, your path is invalid since it contains the symbol `:`, used to separate individual file paths in a list of file paths.